# ReachabilitySwift can't be installed with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, reachability, reachability-swift

In my Podfile, I have:

```
pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3.0'
```

But when I run `pod install`, all the frameworks are setup correctly except ReachabilitySwift:

```
Installing ReachabilitySwift 3 (was 2.4)

[!] Error installing ReachabilitySwift
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift.git /var/folders/cn/1zzgfkjj5xq3hm3g4351087r0000gn/T/d20170922-5156-v06cm4 --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch v3

Cloning into '/var/folders/cn/1zzgfkjj5xq3hm3g4351087r0000gn/T/d20170922-5156-v06cm4'...
warning: Could not find remote branch v3 to clone.
fatal: Remote branch v3 not found in upstream origin
```

With this [GitHub link](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/issues/138), I found a recommended solution:

> Please add a
>
> ```
> s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
>     'SWIFT_VERSION' => '3.0'
> }
> ```
>
> to the podspec file.
>   Otherwise, there will be an error after each pod install.

But I don't know where to find the podspec file and in what place to insert this string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to edit the podspec file manually, that would involve forking the project.

The project's podspec file references a wrong tag, you should specify the correct tag and use that until the podspec file is fixed.

**From a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift):**

> Podspec is still looking for the old v3 tag, for now manually specify the repo and tag will fix:
>
> ```
> pod 'ReachabilitySwift', :git => 'https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift.git', :tag => 'v3.0'
> ```

Comment: I checked. In this case I will instal https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability , not https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift . Framework really changed from ReachabilitySwift to Reachability . But pods are not changed, so it's strange that I can't install it with pod 'ReachabilitySwift'